# Does dictionary objects allows to add key as null at the runtime addition or throw exceptions or skip them?

Tags: excel, vbscript, wsh, vba

Suppose I do have an array list say:

```
 Dim Set myQueue= CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
 Dim Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Now I perform the below:

```
    myQueue.Enqueue("jumped")
    myQueue.Enqueue("over")
    myQueue.Enqueue("the")
    myQueue.Enqueue("lazy")
    myQueue.Enqueue("dog")
    myQueue.Enqueue("Cat")
```

Then perform the remove operation:

```
   myQueue .RemoveRange(2,4)
```

So the array list contains values like = (jumped,over,,,,Cat).

Now the below operation would thorugh any exceptions or during the addition of keys,items will it skip `null` values automatically?

```
   For i=0 to myQueue.Capacity - 1

     Dic(i)=0

   next
```

Comment: have you tried it? Adding Null to a dictionary is OK as a key or value

Comment: @PhilipABarnes that means I need to take care of those nulls during key addition, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call RemoveRange() on an ArrayList it does not leave behind NULL values but removes the requested elements and repositions the array. So in your example you would be left with `jumped,over,Cat`. You can also use the `.Count` property to return the elements in the array and this is kept uptodata with any additions/ removals.

Comment: according to you `Count` and `Capacity` array will always be equal. Is it?

Comment: So the for `loop` will not throw any error if the `Arraylis`t is contigous,but before them assigning to the dicobject's key,should i need to perform any operations on the `Arraylist` items?

Comment: I never said Count and Capacity are always equal. ArrayList resizes the array when Count = Capacity to allow for further growth. It resizes to 4, 8, 16 etc. I would suggest you test all permutations in VBA and if you have any issues with the code you are not able to solve post another question.